# XOR or add in one time pads?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad

Is there any difference in adding the plain text and key vs using xor instead(apart from the performance improvements)?

Comment: If you do proper group addition, then there's no difference in security.

Comment: I did it by adding the ascii values of the pt and k modulo 256 and haven't had problems so far.

Comment: What "performance improvements", BTW?

Comment: I believe a computer can xor in one go which is faster than adding the values then using modulo.

Comment: @otus, if you do it in assembly, XOR is much much faster than addition (which is implicetely performed $\bmod 2^{64}$) because for the CPU it's much simpler than this pesky addition with the carry and this stuff. And mod 256 is perfectly secure.

Comment: @SEJPM, not really. On all but the smallest CPUs, a word-sized modular addition typically takes the same time as a word-sized XOR. (In some cases it can effectively take *less*, like if it is combined into LEA on some x86.) It's really just "weird" moduli that will usually cause a slowdown. Or using some high level language that doesn't optimize it away.

Comment: @otus I know this is one for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ but presumably by "weird moduli", you mean any moduli that's not base 2^n (or preferably 256^n) as it's implicit on a hardware level that XOR requires minimal logic instructions.

Comment: @IamNick, if it is not a power of two then XOR is not really an alternative anyway. I meant sizes the CPU doesn't support natively (like 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits for amd64). Then you may need an additional instruction to mask the carry.

Comment: @otus, good point actually; well made. This thread should be left to die now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no security difference; there are a handful of practical ones:

- With xor, you can have the same code to do encryption and decryption
- With xor, you don't have to pick a 'word size'; a larger CPU can handle 4 or 8 bytes at a time, while a microcontroller can handle 1 byte at a time, without changing the ciphertext
- With xor, you don't have to worry about endianness (which you would if you, say, added words modulo $2^{32}$

While these are all minor differences, they all point towards xor being slightly better from a practical standpoint